# How to rewrite url for custom controller path?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, controllers, router

I have created a controller for my custom module. My controller path is like http://www.example.com/test/index/index which is displaying page correctly. I want to perform URL-rewrite for converting `/test/index/index` to `/test.html`

**Based on the first answer, I have modified my code as below:**

I tried to do something like following, in my `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <test>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </test>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<global>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <test>  <!-- observer identifier -->
                <class>Pfay_Test_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </test>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>

</global>
```

In `/app/code/local/Pfay/Test/Controller/Router.php`

```
<?php
     class Pfay_Test_Controller_Router extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract{
/**
 * Initialize Controller Router
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */

public function initControllerRouters($observer){
    $front=$observer->getEvent()->getFront();
    $front->addRouter('test',$this);

}


/* validate and modify the  request
 *  Params Zend_Controller_Request_Htt
 */
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){

    /* If Magento Magento is not install then 
     * redirect to installer url
     */
    If(!Mage::isInstalled()):
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;

    endif;
    $requestPathInfo=trim($request->getPathInfo(),'/');
    Mage::log('aaa'.$requestPathInfo.'StoreId'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), null, 'logfile.log');
    /* check -review-form not exit
     * then immediate return false
     */
    if($requestPathInfo!='test.html'):
        return  false;
    endif;


    $request->setModuleName('test')
        ->setControllerName('index')
        ->setActionName('index');
    $request->setAlias(
        Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
        'test.html'
    );


    return  true;
  }
 }
```

In `/app/code/local/Pfay/Test/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Observer{

public function add($observer){

    $identifier=$observer->getEvent()->getCondition();
    Mage::log('aaa', null, 'logfile.log');

     }

   }
```

But when I type http://www.example.com/test.html , it is still showing `404 error`.Can anybody hint out where it is going wrong?

I am using `Magento 1.9`, `Apache 2.4` and `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest,solution, Go to Catalog-> `URL Rewrite Management`.

Click ‘Add URL Rewrite’
Select “Create URL Rewrite:” drop-down to “Custom”
Then enter “ID Path”: category/55 or anything without space (this may be not available in Magento EE),
Enter “Request Path as  "test.html*  target test/index/index

In this case,it  will `better idea` to  create custom route like `Mage_Cms` module.

Where depends on `request path using Custom route match`   `internally` set 
the `request path`

- `modules ->CustommoduleNameSpace_ModuleName`
- `controller  ->indexController.php`
- `Action ->indexAction.`

Customer will see that like

```
http://www.domain.com/test.html
```

but internally it hit to

```
http://www.domain.com/test/index/index/
```

Follow the link to implement [this functonality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575631/magento-load-review-form-on-external-page)

Controller code should be :

```
<?php
class CustommoduleNameSpace_ModuleName_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract{
    /**
     * Initialize Controller Router
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */

    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front=$observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('test',$this);

    }


    /* validate and modify the  request
     *  Params Zend_Controller_Request_Htt
     */
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){

        /* If Magento Magento is not install then 
         * redirect to installer url
         */
        If(!Mage::isInstalled()):
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
                 exit;

        endif;
        $requestPathInfo=trim($request->getPathInfo(),'/');
        Mage::log('aaa'.$requestPathInfo.'StoreId'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), null, 'logfile.log');
        /* check -review-form not exit
         * then immediate return false
         */ 
        if($requestPathInfo!='test.html'):
            return  false;
        endif;


        $request->setModuleName('test') 
                    ->setControllerName('index')
                 ->setActionName('index');
        $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                'customindentifier'
        );


        return  true;

    }


}
```

Comment: In the code Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
 'customindentifier'                                                                                                  what 'customindentifier' means?I replaced it with 'test.html',btw it's working now.

Comment: little busy .Wil be reply after 5PM